# Distinct rows based on One column in multi union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct, union

I am working to build a hierarchical menu which is based on 4 table. after doing research the only solution i can think of is to do it with the UNION so far i am close but still i don't have the desired result.

4 Table which i am using are

1. Page Table with PageID as PK *(Which holds actual pages for cms)*
2. Article Table with  PageID as FK *(Which has article)*
3. Article Category Table with PageID as FK *(this table has article category)*
4. Magazine Table with PageID as FK *(Magazine table holds magazine information)*

I had to make some changes to my database based on some suggestion made to my [previous question which is directly related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121623/how-to-create-hierarchical-menu-from-different-table-based-on-sample-database-st), Previous question has details about database.

I need these columns `PID, MENU, Handler,PageLangID, ParentID,IssueID, CatID,MenuPosition`
to create my Hierarchical Menu  I wrote the below which get me the required column but i am not able run the DISTINCT on Menu so that i will get only Unique Row and based on that result set i can create my menu.

When i try to add `DISTINCT (Menu)` it generates me syntax error.

I am not sure based on my requirement which is mention in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121623/how-to-create-hierarchical-menu-from-different-table-based-on-sample-database-st) whether this approach is fine or i should take some other approach which is not ambiguous or more professional

**QUERY**

```
 SELECT PID, MENU, Handler, PageLangID, ParentID,IssueID, CatID, MenuPosition 
FROM (
    --Pages Table 
    SELECT PageId AS PID,SUBSTRING(PageName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, PageLangID,PageInheritance AS ParentID, 1 AS IssueID, 1 AS CatID, 
            PageLinkPosition as MenuPosition  FROM pg_Pages  WHERE PageLangID = 1
    UNION
    --Article Table
    SELECT p.PageID as PID, SUBSTRING(c.ArticleCategoryName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler,LanguageID,p.PageID  AS ParentID,IssueID,c.ArticleCategoryID AS CatID,
           1 AS MenuPosition FROM art_Articles a JOIN art_Category  c ON a.ArticleCategoryID = c.ArticleCategoryID JOIN pg_pages p ON p.PageID = a.PageID    WHERE LanguageID =1  
    UNION
    --Article Category Table
    SELECT p.PageID AS PID, SUBSTRING(c.ArticleCategoryName,0,20) AS MENU,SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler, LangID,p.PageID,1, ArticleCategoryID,
          1 AS MenuPosition FROM art_Category c JOIN pg_Pages p ON c.PageID = p.PageID WHERE LangID =1  
    UNION
    --Magazine Table
    SELECT p.PageID AS PID, CAST(IssueCode AS varchar(10)),SUBSTRING(p.PageInternalLinkURL,0,24) AS Handler,LangID,p.PageID AS ParentID, m.IssueID AS IssueID, 1, 
           1 AS MenuPosition FROM Magazine m   JOIN pg_pages p ON m.PageID = p.PageID   WHERE LangID =1   
    ) AS T  WHERE T.PageLangID = 1 ORDER BY MenuPosition
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PID         MENU                 Handler                  PageLangID  ParentID    IssueID     CatID       MenuPosition
----------- -------------------- ------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
5           Book Review          Articles.aspx            1           5           5           18          1
5           Business             Articles.aspx            1           5           5           16          1
5           Group News           Articles.aspx            1           5           5           6           1
5           Infrastructure       Articles.aspx            1           5           5           17          1
5           Politics             Articles.aspx            1           5           1           1           1
5           Politics             Articles.aspx            1           5           3           1           1
5           Politics             Articles.aspx            1           5           4           1           1
5           Politics             Articles.aspx            1           5           5           1           1
6           Book Review          Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           18          1
6           Business             Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           16          1
6           Chairman's Message   Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           9           1
6           Culture              Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           3           1
6           Economy              Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           2           1
6           Editorial Message    Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           8           1
6           Finance              Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           19          1
6           Group News           Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           6           1
6           Habtoor Leighton Gr  Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           5           1
6           Infrastructure       Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           17          1
6           Lifestyle            Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           20          1
6           People               Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           7           1
6           Politics             Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           1           1
6           Sports               Article-Category.aspx    1           6           1           4           1
12          102                  Default.aspx             1           12          3           1           1
12          103                  Default.aspx             1           12          4           1           1
12          106                  Default.aspx             1           12          1           1           1
12          109                  Default.aspx             1           12          5           1           1
1           Home                 Default.aspx             1           0           1           1           10
11          Video                Videos.aspx              1           10          1           1           10
2           About Us             Page.aspx                1           0           1           1           20
5           Articles             Articles.aspx            1           0           1           1           20
6           Categories           Article-Category.aspx    1           0           1           1           25
3           News                 News.aspx                1           0           1           1           30
12          Archive              Default.aspx             1           0           1           1           40
10          Multimedia           Multimedia.aspx          1           0           1           1           60
```

Comment: The above `output` is your expected output or current output? If it is the latter, could you please also show us what's your expected output? :)

Comment: It is the current output.. If you will see it has multiple entries of `Politics`

Comment: I also want to further refine this query so that it will only show those categories which actually has article & for that particular issue

Answer (score 0):

You have used order by in the outer select statement. 
As order by not working with the distinct statement,

So, Do the DISTINCT in a subselect and the ORDER BY in the outer select.

Hope this will be helpful to solve out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need DISTINCT on all SELECT statements

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID, MENU, Handler, PageLangID, ParentID,IssueID, CatID, MenuPosition
...
```

Comment: I used that but it doesn't give me desired result in some case I will try DISTINCT ON article & article Category table table to see if it works

Comment: What IssueID from these: 1, 3, 4, or 5 you want for distinct on Politics menu

Comment: I want to make it distinct on `MENU` over all results

Comment: I will see if i can drop the query for Article Table query then i can run DISTINCT on main that is getting me the desired result. but for now i will just see if i need this query.

Comment: because your Article Table contains different IssueID on the identical MENU. You need to choose only one for DISTINCT

Comment: I have removed Article Table Query now i am getting the desired result, OR i can modify this query to get me the article title that will make my menu more flexible.

Comment: Simple way removing IssueID of your result set or assigned as 1